# User selected date range to weeks via linq etc

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, aggregate-functions

I have a form which user select start and end date to get data.
Although user select start and end date i have to show data from table week by week in date range.

My model is simple

```
public class DateBetween
      public Datetime StartDate{ get;set;}
      public Datetime EndDate{ get;set;}
```

I get list of my datas between these dates from database

```
IList<Revenue> datas = DB.CreateCrateria(typeof(Revenue))
              .Add(Restrictions.Bt("Date", model.startDate, model.endDate))
              .List<Revenue>();

public class Revenue
      public int Id{ get;set;}
      public double Revenue { get;set;}
      public Datetime RevenueDate{ get;set;}
```

Example:

```
id     Date         Revenue  
1      10/11/2011   554 
2      11/10/2011   500
```

etc

If user select date like 6/30/2011 and 10/15/2011

I want to show to user

```
 Week         Date                     Avg.Revenue 
Week 1        6/30/2011-7/2/2011       587 
Week 2        7/3/2011-7/9/2011        650
```

> ...
>
> etc

Is there any recommendation doing with aggregate funct. in linq

Answer (score 0):

You could use a handwritten LINQ or use this answer:

[LINQ query to split an ordered list into sublists of contiguous points by some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469828/linq-query-to-split-an-ordered-list-into-sublists-of-contiguous-points-by-some-c/7470048#7470048)

Example: using nothing else than plain Linq and DateTime/Calendar:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var data = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddDays(rnd.Next(-91000,91000)/24));

var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
Func<DateTime, int> twoWeeks = dt => (dt.Year * 100) + 2 * (calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday) / 2);

var by2weeks = data.GroupBy(twoWeeks);

foreach (var period in by2weeks.OrderBy(g => g.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", period.Key, string.Join(", ", period));
}
```

For C# 3.5 and earlier `string.Join(", ", period)`

```
string.Join(", ", period.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: main question is how to grouping date range into weeks and aggregate with other db operations.

Comment: ahem, I just did a sample; you don't say you actually meant LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-EF? I'm never sure what works with those :( I hope my way of grouping helps

Answer (score 0):

The trick was getting the exact calendar start date for each week in any given year, and for that I looped on DateTime's Office Automation method.  Doing that produced a Dictionary with 53 entries.  After that, it was all standard LINQ grouping and referencing into the dictionary for the start date.

```
        Calendar cal =  Calendar.ReadOnly(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        DirectoryInfo rdi = new DirectoryInfo(Root);  // get all files in the root directory
        List<FileInfo> allfis = rdi.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        var a = allfis.GroupBy(q=>cal.GetYear(q.LastWriteTime)); 
        foreach (var b in a.Where(q=>q.Key==2011)) // this year only
        {
            double yearStartOaDate = new DateTime(b.Key, 1, 1).ToOADate();
            double yearEndOaDate = yearStartOaDate + 365;
            // get exact start dates for each week
            Dictionary<int, DateTime> weekStartingDates = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
            while (yearStartOaDate <= yearEndOaDate)
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(yearStartOaDate);
                int ww = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
                if(!weekStartingDates.ContainsKey(ww))
                {
                    weekStartingDates.Add(ww, dt);
                }
                yearStartOaDate += ww == 1 ? 1 : 7;
            }
            var c = b.GroupBy(q => cal.GetWeekOfYear(q.LastWriteTime, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday)).OrderBy(q=>q.Key);
            foreach(var d in c)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Between " + weekStartingDates[d.Key].ToShortDateString() + " and " + weekStartingDates[d.Key].AddDays(6).ToShortDateString() + " there were " + d.Count() + " files modified");
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText("results.txt", sb.ToString());
```

And the results were...

Between 09/01/2011 and 15/01/2011 there were 22 files modified

Between 12/06/2011 and 18/06/2011 there were 11 files modified

etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

First Select date object with WeekOfYear then group on it and ...

```
    var result = datas.Select(p => new
    {
        week = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(p.Date.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), p.Date.Value).Value / 7,
        Date= p.Date,
        Revenue= p.Revenue
    }).GroupBy(p => p.week)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        week=p.Key,
        Date=string.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}",p.Min(q=>q.Date))+"-"+string.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}",p.Max(q=>q.Date))
        Revenue=p.Average(q=>q.Revenue)
    }).ToList();
```