# linq group by contiguous blocks

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have following data:

> Time      Status
>   10:00     On
>   11:00     Off
>   12:00     Off
>   13:00     Off
>   14:00     Off
>   15:00     On
>   16:00     On

How could I group that using Linq into something like

> [On, [10:00]], [Off, [11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00]], [On, [15:00, 16:00]]

Comment: I think this is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469828/linq-query-to-split-an-ordered-list-into-sublists-of-contiguous-points-by-some-c

Comment: Is the question, given the following data who can I determine if the entity is On/Off at a given time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a `GroupAdjacent` extension, such as the one listed [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs).

And then it's as simple as:

```
var groups = myData.GroupAdjacent(data => data.OnOffStatus);
```

Comment: A `GroupAdjacent` extension method is available in the [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) package.

Comment: Link is broken, making this answer incomplete.

Comment: Thanks; fixed the link.

Answer (score 6):

You could also do this with one Linq query using a variable to keep track of the changes, like this.

```
int key = 0;
var query = data.Select(
    (n,i) => i == 0 ? 
        new { Value = n, Key = key } : 
        new 
        { 
            Value = n, 
            Key = n.OnOffFlag == data[i - 1].OnOffFlag ? key : ++key 
        })
    .GroupBy(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Basically it assigns a key for each item that increments when the current item does not equal the previous item.  Of course this assumes that your data is in a List or Array, otherwise you'd have to try a different method

Answer (score 4):

Here is a *hardcore* LINQ solution by using `Enumerable.Zip` to compare contiguous elements and generate a contiguous key:

```
var adj = 0;
var t = data.Zip(data.Skip(1).Concat(new TimeStatus[] { null }),
        (x, y) => new { x, key = (x == null || y == null || x.Status == y.Status) ? adj : adj++ }
    ).GroupBy(i => i.key, (k, g) => g.Select(e => e.x));
```

Comment: thank god I knew what this was without actually trying to parse this

Answer (score 3):

It can be done as.

1. Iterate over collection.
2. Use `TakeWhile<Predicate>` condition is text of first element of collection On or Off.
3. Iterate over the subset of from point one and repeat above step and concatenate string.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the list and assign a contiguous key e.g define a class:

```
public class TimeStatus
{
    public int ContiguousKey { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

You would assign values to the contiguous key by looping through, maintaining a count and detecting when the status changes from On to Off and so forth which would give you a list like this:

```
List<TimeStatus> timeStatuses = new List<TimeStatus> 
            {
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 1, Status = "On", Time = "10:00"},
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 1, Status = "On", Time = "11:00"},
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 2, Status = "Off", Time = "12:00"},
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 2, Status = "Off", Time = "13:00"},
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 2, Status = "Off", Time = "14:00"},
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 3, Status = "On", Time = "15:00"},
                new TimeStatus { ContiguousKey = 3, Status = "On", Time = "16:00"}
            };
```

Then using the following query you can extract the Status and grouped Times:

```
    var query = timeStatuses.GroupBy(t => t.ContiguousKey)
    .Select(g => new { Status = g.First().Status, Times = g });
```