# Finding duplicates in an array and its index number

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

work on vs 2010 C#

I have following array and I am trying to find if there are duplicates
in the array. I also want to find out their index

```
red 
red
Grey
Grey
red
blue
blue
Green
White
Grey
```

and I want to get duplicate count of every value of array, for example:

```
red    Count=2  index=0 (contain the duplicate cluster start index)
Grey   Count=2  index=2
red    Count=1  index=4
blue   Count=2  index=5
Green  Count=1  index=6
White  Count=1  index=7
Grey   Count=1  index=8
```

help me to fix my bellow syntax to full fill the above result

```
var result = from p in a //a is the list
                         group p by p into g
                         select new { value=g.Key,count=g.Count()};
```

Comment: What does that code produce and how would you like to see it changed?

Comment: @shamim - Did you got a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var dupl = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
var d = a.Distinct();
for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; ++i)
{
   int match = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < a.Count; ++j)
   {
       if (a[j] == d[i])
       {
          ++match;
          if (++match > 1)
          {
              if (dupl.ContainsKey(d[i])) dupl[d[i]].Add(j);
              else
              {
                 dupl.Add(d[i], new List<int>());
                 dupl[d[i]].Add(j);
              }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

This will produce you a dictionary having its key as the duplicate string (which exists > 1) and its value a list of indices in `a` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupAdjacent` extension method written [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx). Took this reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748510/linq-group-by-contiguous-blocks). Your query will become very easy:-

```
var result = colors.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i })
                               .GroupAdjacent(x => x.Value)
                               .Select(x => new
                               {
                                   Color = x.Key,
                                   Count = x.Count(),
                                   Index = x.First().Index
                               });
```

Complete Working Fiddle [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l2biRO).

Comment: Rahul Singh, thanks for reply.your syntax are incredible but i am not interested about extension method process.thanks again for reply

Answer (score -2):

Here is the final working thing:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var AS = new[] { "red", "red", "Grey", "Grey", "blue" };
            var zippedList = AS.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, AS.Length), (s, i) => new { s, i });

            var finalResult =
                from a in zippedList
                group a by a.s into g
                select new { key = g.Key, result = new { list = g.Select(o => o.i).ToList(), count = g.Count() } };
            foreach (var item in finalResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.key);
                Console.WriteLine(item.result.count);
                Console.WriteLine(item.result.list);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Debug View of Program]

<strike>Something like this works</strike>

```
from a in AS
from b in Enumerable.Range(0,AS.Conunt()-1)
into (a,b)
group by a
```

Then you can add the count to the result easily by counting each group length.

I don't have visual studio nor a good memory to remember LINQ but it would be enough to start with.

Comment: To those ... who down-voted, I just wanted to show that the functional style of code is way simpler than imperative style.

Comment: It was not my downvote but your solution does not produce what the author showed in his example. Add another 'red' at the end of the array and you will get the same number of results (3). But he wants only to group the consecutive items. In his desired results, he has 'red' two times