# LINQ Grouping records based on a key and following records

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, .net-core

I would like to know whether the following can be achieved with LINQ. At this point I group by "MeetingType" but the resultset isn't what I am looking for as I would also like to keep the Grouping based on the chronological occurrence of the Meeting Type.

So basically in the example below you will see that there were 4 PoolDiscussion Meetings. In this case I do not want all 4 records grouped together as between the 3rd and 4th meeting Pool Discussion another Meeting of different type occured, so what I would like is to have three groups where the 1st would be PoolDiscussion (have 3 record) the Second would be Landscaping (1 record) and the Last would be PoolDiscussion (1 Record)

Let's say I have the following data record
Database records

| MeetingName | MeetingType | MeetingDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| With John | Pool Discussion | 2020-01-02 |
| With Emily | Pool Discussion | 2020-01-02 |
| With Ed | Pool Discussion | 2020-01-03 |
| With John | Landscaping | 2020-01-03 |
| With Ed | Pool Discussion | 2020-01-04 |

So in this case what I am trying to do is have a JSON output in the following structure (note how there are 2 "PoolDiscussions" Grouping this

```
{
    "Meetings": [
        {
            "PoolDiscussion": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With John",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-02"
                },
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With Emily",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-02"
                },
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With Ed",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-03"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Landscaping": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With John",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-03"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PoolDiscussion": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With Ed",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-04"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: See one of these questions: [linq group by contiguous blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14748510), [LINQ to find series of consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20469416)

Comment: How do you know if 'pool discussion with ed' comes before or after the 'landscaping with john'?

Comment: @Jonathan it is based to the DateTime, my actual data also has a time attached to the DateField

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish exactly what you want with a single LINQ query. The reason is that you don't have a unique key to group by. You are basically trying to group by meeting type and the date, so you can get close with the following, but you will have an extra "PoolDiscussion" record for the meeting "With Ed" on the 3rd...

```
from meeting in data
group meeting by new { Type = meeting.MeetingType, Date = meeting.MeetingDateTime } into mts
select new { Key = mts.Key.Type, Value = mts.ToList() }).ToList()
```

This will produce the following:

```
[
        {
            "PoolDiscussion": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With John",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-02"
                },
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With Emily",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-02"
                }
             ]
        },
        {  "PoolDiscussion": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With Ed",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-03"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Landscaping": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With John",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-03"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PoolDiscussion": [
                {
                    "MeetingName": "With Ed",
                    "MeetingDate": "2020-01-04"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Once you have this data set you can loop through it and collapse the adjacent "PoolDiscussion" records

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple partial-LINQ solution, though I wonder about a slightly more efficient, or completely LINQ-based, approach:

```
var groupedMeetings = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Meeting>>>();
while (meetings.Any())
{
    var group = meetings.TakeWhile((meeting, index) =>
    {
        return index == 0 || meeting.MeetingType == meetings[index - 1].MeetingType;
    });
    
    groupedMeetings.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(group.First().MeetingType, group.ToList()));

    // Skip past the meetings we've already processed.
    meetings = meetings.SkipWhile((meeting, index) =>
    {
        return index == 0 || meeting.MeetingType == meetings[index - 1].MeetingType;
    }).ToList();
}
```

And here's a non-LINQ approach for comparison:

```
var groupedMeetings = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Meeting>>>();

var i = 0;
while (i < meetings.Count)
{
    var meetingType = meetings[i].MeetingType;

    // A group will always consist of at least one meeting.
    var group = new List<Meeting>
    {
        meetings[i++]
    };

    while (i < meetings.Count - 1 && meetings[i].MeetingType == meetings[i - 1].MeetingType)
    {
        group.Add(meetings[i++]);
    }

    groupedMeetings.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(meetingType, group));
}
```

Both of these approaches assume the meetings are already ordered correctly prior to being processed, and preserve that ordering.

Assuming the following class:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string MeetingType { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime MeetingDate { get; set; }
}
```

This:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd"
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedMeetings, settings));
```

generates JSON equivalent to your sample:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "Pool Discussion",
    "Value": [
      {
        "MeetingName": "With John",
        "MeetingDate": "2020-01-02"
      },
      {
        "MeetingName": "With Emily",
        "MeetingDate": "2020-01-02"
      },
      {
        "MeetingName": "With Ed",
        "MeetingDate": "2020-01-03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "Landscaping",
    "Value": [
      {
        "MeetingName": "With John",
        "MeetingDate": "2020-01-03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "Pool Discussion",
    "Value": [
      {
        "MeetingName": "With Ed",
        "MeetingDate": "2020-01-04"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```