# entity framework - sort the rows(few records) in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I've a list with ascending sorted manner of distance.

like need to sort 4 to 6

**Not Sorted:**

[image: image1]

but I wanted to sort it like this,
after sorting in distance manner now wanted to sort list based on availability if slots as shown in below
sort on records of same distance only.

id from 4 to 6 is sorted

**Sorted:**

[image: image 2 sorted]

Does anyone have solution for this?

Comment: I don't really get your sort logic… - why is ID=8 on the very bottom? Why are ID=4,5,6 sorted the way they are, what logic should be applied to get the desired result - why is the correct order ID=5,6,4 - I just can't figure out what the logic there is?!?

Comment: EntityFramework and Linq allow you to use your custom comparator that might fulfil your needs.
collection.OrderBy(x => x.Distance>).ThenBy(y => y.SlotAvailability, yourComparer);

Comment: @Wokuo can you explain with example?

Comment: @RandRandom logic is , i want to sort the other columns as per shown in 2nd image. if 3 records have same distance value but different type of availability of slots than it should be sorted as availability "yes" should be first in those 3 records and than records with "in future" value and than records with "no" value.

Comment: And only if exactly 3 records with the identical distance are next to each other? so if on first image the ID = 5 wasn't there it would do nothing?

Comment: You can try to use .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ThenBy(x => x.Distance).ThenBy(x=>x.SlotAvailability) if slot availablity is a numeric value, then try to order them to they are in the order you want

Comment: @Paritosh - that would sort nothing - since the Id is unique and the ThenBys are irrelavant - ThenBy only works on non unique items - So OrderBy(x) if x has same items ThenBy(y) if y has same items ThenBy(z) and so on - you could do it by `.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ThenBy(x=>x.SlotAvailability).ThenBy(x => x.Id).` - but this would rearrange his ID=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to only sort chunks of data in your complete list, than I would suggest to use one of the following methods to group your data into chunks.

1. [LINQ query — Data aggregation (Group Adjacent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879197/linq-query-data-aggregation-group-adjacent)
2. [LINQ query to split an ordered list into sublists of contiguous points by some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469828/linq-query-to-split-an-ordered-list-into-sublists-of-contiguous-points-by-some-c)
3. (Recommended Solution) https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs 
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/

For the following example I used the `GroupAdjacent` as described in the first link.

So here it goes:

```
//class for test data
public class Data
{
    public int    Id               { get; set; }
    public int    Distance         { get; set; }
    public string SlotAvailability { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ID={Id} | Distance={Distance} | SlotAvailability={SlotAvailability}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //test data
        var lst = new List<Data>()
        {
            new Data() {Id = 1, Distance = 5, SlotAvailability  = "yes"},
            new Data() {Id = 2, Distance = 6, SlotAvailability  = "yes"},
            new Data() {Id = 3, Distance = 8, SlotAvailability  = "no"},
            new Data() {Id = 4, Distance = 9, SlotAvailability  = "no"},
            new Data() {Id = 5, Distance = 9, SlotAvailability  = "yes"},
            new Data() {Id = 6, Distance = 9, SlotAvailability  = "in future"},
            new Data() {Id = 7, Distance = 11, SlotAvailability = "in future"},
            new Data() {Id = 8, Distance = 9, SlotAvailability  = "in future"},
        };

        //group the results into chunks
        var groupedList = lst.GroupAdjacent(x => x.Distance)

        //apply the sort logic - this assumes that you only want to sort if there are more or equals to 3 items in the group
        var sortedList = groupedList.SelectMany(x =>
        {
            if (x.Count() < 3) //if the count of the group is below 3 return it as it is
                return x.AsEnumerable();

            //if the Count is greater or equals to 3 sort the Group by SlotAvailability
            return x.OrderBy(y =>
            {
                switch (y.SlotAvailability)
                {
                    case "yes":
                        return 1;
                    case "in future":
                        return 2;
                    case "no":
                        return 3;

                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            });
        });

        //print result
        foreach (var data in sortedList)
            Console.WriteLine(data);

        //wait for user input
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you don't want the `SlotAvailability` sort logic to be applied if there are 3 or more items than use this instead

```
var sortedList = groupedList.SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y =>
    {
        switch (y.SlotAvailability)
        {
            case "yes":
                return 1;
            case "in future":
                return 2;
            case "no":
                return 3;

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Hi, Rand Random, Thanks for help. alright, here i've slightly changes in list. slotavailability itself is a list in which one property named as "slot type" has value which maybe "yes" or "no" or "in future", can you edit your answer as per this?

Comment: Yes, can I edit it - but I have one question - since `SlotAvailability` is a list - what should happen if that list has multiple entries with different values in the `SlotType` property? - Or should I ignore those cases and only check the first entry in the list?

Comment: slottype has different values either "in future" or "no-slot" or time of slot(in my work requirement). Actually your above code works perfect for me, i've just changed it in my work according to requirement. Thanks a lot for reply. it works perfect. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm assuming here that your values for `SlotAvailability` are the strings we're seeing in the table. You could *weight* the `OrderBy` statement to make sure things are ordered as `yes, in future, no` as you want.

The result would be you're ordering your records by `Distance` ascending *then* by your weighted `SlotAvailability` values (also ascending).

I'm also assuming you've only got those 3 values possible for `SlotAvailability`

for example:

`.OrderBy(n=>n.Distance).ThenBy(n=>n. SlotAvailability == "yes" ? 1 : (n. SlotAvailability == "no" ? 3 : 2));`

As you can see, I'm assigning the weight (and thus order) as so:

- 1 = yes
- 2 = in future
- 3 = no

Comment: This won't produce the result OP is showing in his second image - as it will also rearrange the entry with ID=8. ID=8 will be between ID=6 and ID=4.

Comment: Hi Rand - I'm assuming (which I know could be my downfall) that the OP actually _does_ intend it to be this way. I'll happily bow my head in shame if I'm wrong and deduct myself some developer kudos points!

Comment: Yeah, I also assume it - thats why I asked for clarification in the comments - sadly, OP didn't fully explain what about ID=8 in his response. :(

Comment: Could be an honest typo/mistake on the OP's part....or...the down-votes are coming